# Devise helpers return nil

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have this line in the `<...>/layouts/application.html.erb` :

```
<% if client_signed_in? %>
```

To render different html for unsigned/signed clients. At first I was using SQLite3 and everything worked fine, until I've tried to use MySQL instead. So, I ran migration file, inserted the same data with `rake db:seed` and registered using Devise API, then I checked that data was inserted in the database. Then I tried to sign in with the same API and get the following error for the line above:

> undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass

Or a more specific version from the log :

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass):
    11: <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    12:   <div class="container">
    13:     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    14:       <% if client_signed_in? %>
    15:           <li class="dropdown">
    16:             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    17:               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> 
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3350269212856659822_70353324331380'
```

I get the same for all Devise helpers, like `current_client` (the corresponding model is `Client`) and so on.

`database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

`ApplicationHelper` :

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def resource_name
        :client
    end

    def resource
        @resource ||= Client.new
    end

    def devise_mapping
        @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:client]
    end 
end
```

`Client` model :

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable
end
```

session dump:

> _csrf_token: "YYUINrP+2synbq2bayWVozyo3nfGVtzkxDd9QJn9S4k="
>   flash: {"discard"=>[], "flashes"=>{"notice"=>"Signed in successfully."}}
>   session_id: "6ab5a131dc9300e2a3c0dbd4e00218f0"
>   warden.user.client.key: [[2], "$2a$10$bqpnIBKi4XCy64TH1zzhB."]

So, as you can see, session is not empty and it takes correct `id` from the model/db, the process of signing in is also successful.

env dump :

```
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.1"
HTTP_ACCEPT:"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip,deflate,sdch"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: "max-age=0"
REMOTE_ADDR: "::1"
REMOTE_HOST: "::1"
```

Comment: Please post your entire error message.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson : Can you be more specific? I get only the message above.Do you need the framework trace?

Comment: Good that helps. Can you post the code for your method `client_signed_in?` please? And, are you sure that's one long method name, and not supposed to be two methods with a dot i.e. `client.signed_in?`

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson : I don't have any code, it is a Devise method.There is some information [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).I also tried with `signed_in?(:client)`, the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting all the detail. Here's a suggestion to debug it.

Devise auto-generates methods, such as your `client_signed_in?` that isn't working.

You can intercept this method, and find out what's going on, by editing the Devise source code.

Devise has a file `helper.rb` that contains the auto-generation code:

```
def #{mapping}_signed_in?
  !!current_#{mapping}
end

def current_#{mapping}
  @current_#{mapping} ||= warden.authenticate(scope: :#{mapping})
end
```

To intercept the method, you can use a debugger, or print, or raise:

```
def current_#{mapping}
  raise "Devise current mapping #{__method__} symbol is " + (:{mapping}).to_s
  @current_#{mapping} ||= warden.authenticate(scope: :#{mapping})
end
```

If you use pry, or want to learn pry because it's awsome for this kind of debugging: http://www.jackkinsella.ie/2014/06/06/debugging-rails-with-pry-debugger.html

```
def current_#{mapping}
  binding.pry
  @current_#{mapping} ||= warden.authenticate(scope: :#{mapping})
end
```

My guess is this method is where your error is happening, and that the "mapping" variable may be nil.

Comment: somehow it doesn't give any results (with `raise` or `print`) – it just throws the same error.(I am a newbie to ruby and RoR, btw). The thing, that is really disappointing  me, is that it works fine with SQLite database, so maybe it is collation or encoding issue.